# $X$ is connected and $\mathcal{U}$ is a locally finite collection of precompact open sets that covers $X$; then $\mathcal{U}$ has a countable subcover

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I came to this question in the course of trying to prove that if $X$ is a paracompact locally Euclidean Hausdorff space with at most countably many components, then it is second countable. I was able to reach the hypothesis in the thread title, then got stuck. I know this problem in general has been addressed before, but I'm wondering if my approach is valid.

**The following is what I'd like to clarify**, I'm not sure if it's legitimate. Pick any $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$. There are $n_1$ sets in $\mathcal{U}$ that intersect $U_0$, call them $U_1,...,U_{n_1}$. There are $n_2$ sets that intersect any of the $U_0,...,U_{n_1}$, call them $U_{n_1+1},...,U_{n_1+n_2}$. Proceed this way, letting the sets $U_{n_1+...+n_k+1},...,U_{n_1+...+n_k+n_{k+1}}$ be the $n_{k+1}$ sets that intersect any of the preceding $U_i$.

Now, I argue that the open set $U = \bigcup_{i}U_i$ = X. Suppose it does not. For any $x \in U^c$, there is some $U_x \in \mathcal{U}$ that contains $x$, and it must have failed to appear in the list $U_i$; in fact, by construction it must not intersect any of the $U_i$ so $x \in U_x \subset U^c$. Thus $U^c$ is open, so $X$ is the union of two disjoint open sets ($U$ and $U^c$) and thus disconnected, which is a contradiction.

Comment: My mistake, the hypothesis should also assume the sets of $\mathcal{U}$ are precompact. In that case each $U$ intersects only finitely many other sets of $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Yes sorry, edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local finiteness of $\mathscr{U}$ does not ensure that each member of $\mathscr{U}$ intersects only finitely many other members of $\mathscr{U}$: that's a stronger property.

However, you know that your space is locally separable, so it has a locally finite open cover $\mathscr{U}$ whose members are separable. Let $W$ be any separable open set, and let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $W$. For each $x\in D$ the set $\operatorname{ST}(x,\mathscr{U})=\{U\in\mathscr{U}:x\in U\}$ is finite, and

$$\{U\in\mathscr{U}:U\cap W\ne\varnothing\}=\bigcup_{x\in D}\operatorname{ST}(x,\mathscr{U})\;,$$

so $W$ intersects only countably many members of $\mathscr{U}$. Let

$$\operatorname{st}(W,\mathscr{U})=\bigcup\{U\in\mathscr{U}:U\cap W\ne\varnothing\}\;;$$

$\operatorname{st}(W,\mathscr{U})$ is the union of countably many separable sets, so it is also separable. Now fix $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$; $U_0$ is separable. Given a separable open set $U_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, let $U_{n+1}=\operatorname{st}(U_n,\mathscr{U})$; then $U_{n+1}$ is also a separable open set. Let $W(U_0)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$; $W$ is a separable open set.

- Show that $\{W(U):U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ is a partition of $X$ into open subsets, and conclude that $X=W(U)$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$.
- Further deduce that $X$ is the union of countably many members of $\mathscr{U}$.
- Finally, note that we could have assumed additionally that each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ was metrizable and hence Lindelöf, and deduce that $X$ is Lindelöf.